# Make Request before Page Unload

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I am working on single page vue application.

In this application, I am using firebase realtime database for storing users.

I just want to update users 'isOnline' state on firebase, before page unload.

So, I want to make http request. Is it possible ?

Below code not do the trick...

```
new Vue({
  created(){
   window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     apiservice.update(this.user);
     return null
    };
  },
}
```

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-presence?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you firebaser :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
new Vue({
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.updateUser)
  },
  methods: {
    updateUser () {
        console.log('updating user')
    }
  }
})
```